# Why the code produces this answer? [Python]

Tags: python

Basically I'm setting up a code, but for some random reason it always says the answers are wrong.

So, say it is '10 x 10' & I would say it is '100'

The code however says back to me, '**`I'm sorry the answer is 100`**'

**Why the code produces this answer?**

Here is the code:

P.S.: I know that I do not have to do '`Num_(NUMBER)`' for all of it!

```
from random 
import randint 
import random

correct = 0

for i in range (3):
  num_1 = randint (1, 10)
  num_2 = randint (1, 10)
  prob1 = num_1*num_2

print (“What’s %d x %d? “ (num_1, num_2))
ans1 = input ()

If ans1 == prob1:
  print (“That’s the correct answer!  /n”)
  correct = correct +1                                                             
else:
  print (“No I’m afraid the answer is %d. /n” & (prob1))

for n in range (3):
  num_3 = randint (1, 10)
  num_4 = randint (1, 10)
  prob2 = num_3+num_4

print (“What’s %d + %d? “ (num_3, num_4))
ans2 = input ()

If ans2 == prob2:
  print (“That’s the correct answer!  /n”)
  correct = correct +1
else:
  print (“No I’m afraid the answer is %d. /n” & (prob2))

for m in range (4):
  num_5 = randint (1, 10)
  num_6 = randint (1, 10)
  prob3 = num_5 - num_6

print (“What’s %d - %d? “ (num_5, num_6))
ans3 = input ()

If ans3 == prob3:
  print (“That’s the correct answer!  /n”)
  correct = correct +1
else:                                                                                                                              
  print (“No I’m afraid the answer is %d. /n” & (prob3))

print (“I asked you 10 questions, you got %d of them right. “ %(correct))
exit()
```

Comment: You need to fix the indention correctly.

Comment: I don't think that edit helped, it looks like half the program isn't displaying now.

Comment: I've added indentation - the code was pasted with only long wrapping spaces and not line endings - odd..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the probe variable is an integer type. the answer that you get from the user is a string. test it this with:

> print type(ans1)
>
> print type(prob1)

so you need to convert the input from the user to an integer:

> if int(ans1) == prob1